# Number of combinations for long AT&T password

Tags: permutations

AT&T gave me a ridiculously long, $11$ character password for wifi network.  How many possibilities are there for this PW with $11$ digits?  (Seems a super computer couldn't hack it in a hundred years).
$2$ numbers, $2$ special characters, $6$ lower case letters, and $1$ upper case letter.

Comment: Can the numbers/letters be repeated?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Good question. Two letters are the same.  All other numbers and letters are unique.